# ls to find all directories that begin with ./

Tags: linux, shell, unix

> Question:
>
> From within your home directory, perform a ls operation shows all
>   directories that begin with a ".". You should not see plain files, and
>   you should not see the contents of these directories. Example:
>
> ~ $ ls ***_*__*_*_** ../  ./  .ssh/  .ssh2/  .sunw/  .tin/

I ran

```
ls -R .  -d | grep ./
```

and it appears to work.

However when I run  `ls -R .  -d` , I notice that the files are still being listed even with -d. Why is this occurring?

Comment: `ls -R . -d` only gives me `.`.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to recursively search your current directory and list the directories?

Comment: I don't believe you need recursion here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're being asked to show all "dot" directories, viz

```
ls -ad .*/
```

Comment: Thank you that appears to work, but how do you find the '-ad' flag? I noticed that it does not appear in the man page. What does '-ad' stand for and why does my command do incorrectly to return so many results?

Comment: `-ad` is two flags together: `-a` and `-d`. This is equivalent to `ls -a -d .*/` but shorter ;-) You don't need the `-a` here though, see my answer and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The (shortest) answer is:

```
ls -d .*/
```

Because:

- `.*/` is for **all directories that begin with a "."**
- `-d` is for **not seeing the contents of these directories**

Without the `/` at the end, you would see plain files, which would be wrong answer.

Without the `-d` flag, you would see the contents of the directories, which would be wrong answer.

No other flags are necessary.